# Determine Qt libraries linkage

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I'm trying to guess Qt's libraries linkage in a project (.pro) file. I'm using various Qt framework directories: 32 and 64 bit Windows, Linux and Android builds; using static and shared Qt libraries. I've tried several way to check Qt's linkage, but nothing has worked so far.

Try 1:

> qtConfig(static): message("Qt statically linked")

Try 2:

> CONFIG(static, static|shared): message("Qt statically linked")

Try 3:

> static: message("Qt statically linked")

I guessed all previous test would lead the same result, and thus show the "message" when selected Qt build is a static one, but I don't know if it's a Qt Creator issue or if I'm overriding `*CONFIG` variables in project tree. I've checked it out too many times over and I haven't found any problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such Qt-config feature as "static". So the right one is

```
!qtConfig(shared): message("Qt statically linked")
```

As an alternative you can do

```
!contains(QT.global.enabled_features, shared): message("Qt statically linked")
```

But this one is even less documented, so you're better to stick with `qtConfig()` which essentially tests for the same thing.

No. 2 is a test of a build configuration of the user project itself, i.e. if you're building a static or shared library *of your own*.

No. 3 is a *wrong* way to do No. 2, because user's `CONFIG` is allowed to contain *both* shared/static, debug/release etc. at the same time. And only the last one will matter.

Comment: I've used your first option; nevertheless, I've check my whole project tree again and I found an overriding option like `CONFIG += ... shared`. Thanks a lot.